# Add "% of row" calculation into Pivot Table

Tags: c#, excel

If I need "summary functions", I use that method:

```
pivotTable.AddDataField(pivotField, "Name", Excel.XlConsolidationFunction.xlCount);
```

But how add custom calculations?

Particularly "% of row".

Answer (score 0):

Solution - add this calculation after creating:

```
pivotTable.AddDataField(pivotField, "Name", Excel.XlConsolidationFunction.xlSum).Calculation = Excel.XlPivotFieldCalculation.xlPercentOfRow;
```